# AngularJS with TypeScript promise-success this object is window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an angular service that returns a promise.  In my controller, I want to assign values to the controller's "this" object.  In my visual studio editor, it thinks that "this" will be the correct object when I'm editing (this.something is shown in the intellisense), but when this runs, something is undefined because this is the window object.  What am I doing wrong?

```
        this.webapi.getSites().success((data: Array<Isite>): void => {
            this.something = data;  // this becomes the window object so something is undefined.
        }).error(function (error: any) {
        });
```

Unlike other answers, this is not undefined, it is set to the window object.  The transpiled code looks like:

```
    topnav.prototype.loadSiteInfo = function () {
        var _this = this;
        this.webapi.getSites().success(function (data) {
            _this.something = data;
        }).error(function (error) {
        });
    };
```

Seems like it should work to me...

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, [that's how this in Javascript works](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) :)  It's a common problem, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24145178/398606) has a good solution (using `var self = this;`).

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) has a nice explanation as well.

Comment: @SunilD. Notice carefully OP is using arrow operator aka lexical scope resolution operator. Typescript polyfills it in ES5 mode.

Comment: Can you show full relevant code? Is this inside another callback and are you using arrow operator properly there?. Otherwise this should ideally be fine. You have TS compilation set in which mode? Also see how transpiled  code looks like?

Comment: @PSL Doh! I need to learn TypeScript I guess ...

Comment: I added the transpiled code.

Comment: @MikeWitt How is `loadSiteInfo` being called. You would need to show this. Since value of `this` depends upon how it is invoked.

Comment: Constructor calls an activate function and it calls the loadSiteInfo.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

the instance function loadSiteinfo() isn't being called by its object reference. So "this" variable in the function isn't being set properly.

```
var instance = new topnav();

//this is right
instance.loadSiteInfo()

//this is wrong 
var f= instance.loadSiteInfo;
f();
```

**Solution**

you should find the *caller* function and change the logic in a way loadSiteinfo is called by its object reference. You can find the *caller* by putting breakpoint inside loadSiteInfo function and look at the call stack when break point pauses the execution. You can do that in chrome web dev tools (F12)

Comment: Loadsiteinfo is called like this:  "this.loadSiteInfo();"  and it is defined as a member function like: "loadSiteInfo(): void { }" so I believe it is doing it with the instance variable correctly.

Comment: then "this" in this.loadSiteInfo() isn't pointing to right object. You should track it down in call stack.  I suggest you to look how "this" works in JavaScript.